# Is DeviceToDevice copy in a CUDA program needed?

Tags: cuda

I am doing the following two operations:

1. Addition of two array  => `a + b = AddResult`
2. Multiply of two arrays => `AddResult * a = MultiplyResult`

In the above logic, the `AddResult` is an intermediate result and is used in the next mupltiplication operation as input.

```
#define N 4096         // size of array

__global__ void add(const int* a, const int* b, int* c)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (tid < N) 
    {
        c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
    }
}

__global__ void multiply(const int* a, const int* b, int* c)
{
    int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (tid < N) 
    {
        c[tid] = a[tid] * b[tid];
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int T = 1024, B = 4;            // threads per block and blocks per grid
    int a[N], b[N], c[N], d[N], e[N];
    int* dev_a, * dev_b, * dev_AddResult, * dev_Temp, * dev_MultiplyResult;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_a, N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_b, N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_AddResult, N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_Temp, N * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_MultiplyResult, N * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {    
        // load arrays with some numbers
        a[i] = i;
        b[i] = i * 1;
    }

    cudaMemcpy(dev_a, a, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_b, b, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_AddResult, c, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_Temp, d, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_MultiplyResult, e, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //ADD
    add << <B, T >> > (dev_a, dev_b, dev_AddResult);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    //Multiply
    cudaMemcpy(dev_Temp, dev_AddResult, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice); //<---------DO I REALLY NEED THIS?
    multiply << <B, T >> > (dev_a, dev_Temp, dev_MultiplyResult);
    //multiply << <B, T >> > (dev_a, dev_AddResult, dev_MultiplyResult);
    
    //Copy Final Results D to H
    cudaMemcpy(e, dev_MultiplyResult, N * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        printf("(%d+%d)*%d=%d\n", a[i], b[i], a[i], e[i]);
    }

    // clean up
    cudaFree(dev_a);
    cudaFree(dev_b);
    cudaFree(dev_AddResult);
    cudaFree(dev_Temp);
    cudaFree(dev_MultiplyResult);

    return 0;
}
```

In the above sample code, I am transferring the Addition results (i.e. `dev_AddResult`) to another device array (i.e. `dev_Temp`) to perform the multiplication operation.

**QUESTION:** Since the Addition results array (i.e. `dev_AddResult`) is already on the GPU device, do I really need to transfer it to another array? I have already tried to execute the next kernel by directly providing `dev_AddResult` as input and it produced the same results. Is there any risk involved in directly passing the output of one kernel as the input of the next kernel? Any best practices to follow?

Comment: yes, you can use the "output" of one kernel as the "input" to the next.  Why not just try it?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: I already tried and it worked fine but I just wanted to know if its really the correct way and are there any risks involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for the case you have shown, you can use the "output" of one kernel as the "input" to the next, without any copying.  You've already done that and confirmed it works, so I will dispense with any example.  The changes are trivial anyway - eliminate the intervening `cudaMemcpy` operation, and use the same `dev_AddResult` pointer in place of the `dev_Temp` pointer on your multiply kernel invocation.

Regarding "risks" I'm not aware of any for the example you have given.  Moving away from that example to possibly more general usage, you would want to make sure that the add output calculations are finished before being used somewhere else.

Your example already does this, redundantly, using at least 2 mechanisms:

- intervening `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` - this forces the previously issued work to complete
- stream semantics - one rule of stream semantics is that work issued into a particular stream will execute in issue order.  Item B issued into stream X, will not begin until the previously issued item A into stream X has completed.

So you don't really need the `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in this case.  It isn't "hurting" anything from a functionality perspective, but it is probably adding a few microseconds to the overall execution time.

More generally, if you had issued your add and multiply kernel into separate streams, then CUDA provides no guarantees of execution order, even though you "issued" the multiply kernel after the add kernel.

In that case (not the one you have here) if you needed the multiply operation to use the previously computed add results, you would need to enforce that somehow (enforce the completion of the add kernel before the multiply kernel).  You have already shown one method to do that here, using a synchronize call.

Comment: Question regarding your last paragraph: In case of using different streams, what are the other ways besides `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` to enforce synchronization to make sure that the previous kernel is finished before starting the next kernel?

Comment: `cudaStreamWaitEvent()` https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1g7840e3984799941a61839de40413d1d9 on one stream and `cudaEventRecord()` https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__EVENT.html#group__CUDART__EVENT_1gf4fcb74343aa689f4159791967868446 on another stream come to mind to synchronize two streams. Also cudaStreamSynchronize() https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__STREAM.html#group__CUDART__STREAM_1g82b5784f674c17c6df64affe618bf45e for synchronizing host and one GPU stream.

Comment: Or - more sophisticated - Cuda Graphs https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-graphs/ or for specific use cases Dynamic Parallelism https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-dynamic-parallelism-api-principles/

Comment: @Sebastian: Thanks for suggesting about CUDA Graphs. I am looking into it and looks quite promising for my purpose. I am just wondering why my 3 different CUDA books did not mention anything at all about CUDA Graphs.

Comment: Cuda (task) graphs are an advanced feature and where introduced about 3 years ago with CUDA 10.